# Density Slicing of MODIS Raster

Tags: qgis, modis, density

I have some MODIS data processed with MRT tools. They are now in tiff format. Now, I have to complete Density slicing to identify water pixels from the image. The DN higher than 1985 is usually non-innundated area where lower than that value is the inundated area. I completed the task with ILWIS but want to do that with QGIS. Is it possible to do that? Water pixel will be red color and non-inundated area will be green color.

Answer (score 1):

One can use the Style Tab found under Properties to set the color scheme to Discrete and then hit classify (Based on the two classes you choose).